# Cisco ASA 9 update ACL programatically

Tags: cisco-asa

I have been collecting different IP address for VoIP attacks in my infrastructure. These attacks happen every day multiple times.
I have created a service which generates a notification to a python subscriber service which can then execute any action upon request.

Is it possible to add an ACL for each IP address that appears programmatically?. Example via a REST API to ASA.
This is the JSON object I generate, I will just need to configure my python script to use the IP address and send a request to ASA to update ACL, in case IP address already there ignore.

```
{u'Content': u'163.172.120.42', u'From': u'honeypot-ef4b6aa1-d5ca-43f8-92c8-f9840fb5bb9f-deadbeef'}
```

Comment: I think you'll have to do it from the CLI, with an Expect script (or similar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although one way to do it is with programmatically updating an ACL, you might consider

- Building a network config and remotely loading it which is programmatically much simpler than trying to edit the ACL with individual commands
- Blacklisting with DNS, if available on your platform https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/firepower/60/asa-fp-services/asa-with-firepower-services-local-management-configuration-guide-v60/DNS-Policies.html
- "Remote triggered blackhole filtering": using a network routing protocol and sending all the bad traffic there.

This latter technique is written up here, and can be somewhat complex:
https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/security/ios-network-foundation-protection-nfp/prod_white_paper0900aecd80313fac.pdf

It might be possible to do this with something much simpler such as RIP2 with next-hop filled in.

For the use you've indicated, it doesn't sound like you need it to be terribly fast, so I'd start with make-text-file-and-remotely-load it.  The technique is extremely general and rather easy to do.

Run a script to create your ACL commands, probably periodically with cron or similar; then it issues

```
ssh edgerouter1 copy http://localserver/dynamicacl runing-config
```

Note that this "copy" is really a merge, in that it keeps the existing configuration except where the new config explicitely negates something with `no access-list 22` or similar.

You need certificate-based login on the router for this to be practical.

[EDIT]  While trying it I found a small surprise so added details.  I tested with Cisco 2800 router with 15.1.4 as I have no ASA available, server was Ubuntu 16.

To repeat, this is a pretty general way of doing any programmatic configuration of Cisco devices.  In general it's much better to have a fully non-interactive approach, rather than an expect-based approach.  If the interactive system does something unusual your expect script can go wrong in very difficult-to-debug ways.  If this programmed-copy goes wrong you issue the identical command by hand and debug from there.

**Example network** For example clarity, suppose your ASA/router inside address is 192.168.0.1 and you have an internal web server available at 192.168.0.32.

**Generate config** It's supposed you have a program `badaddresses` which produces a list of addresses you want to block.  Make a formatter `mkciscoacl` in awk/python/whatever to produce your appropriate access list, which might look like this:

```
ip access-list extended autobad
 1 deny ip host 10.10.0.5 any
 2 deny ip host 10.10.0.9 any
 1000000 permit ip any any
end
```

**Put on internal web**  Let's imagine you have a cron job which makes that file on the web server, available as http://192.168.0.32/cisco/automatic.conf

**No-prompt** Normally, when you do `copy http://somewhere running-config` you get a prompt confirming the target as `running-config`.  This must be disabled in your configuration.

```
file prompt quiet
```

**Certificate login** You must have a certificate-based login available on your router, as you want the configuration to be entirely automatic. ([Doc](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/security-documents/ssh-using-public-key-authentication-to-ios-and-big-outputs/ta-p/3122001))

```
username autoloader priv 15 secret 12345 ! use a better one!
ip ssh pubkey-chain
  username autoloader
    key-string
      ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDZahXX11Muz3ChJtmVvofZhv5T
        ...
        username@webserver
    exit
  exit
exit
```

**Do whole thing** Make a script `dowholething.sh` which does the whole thing

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
badaddresses | mkciscoacl > /var/www/html/cisco/automatic.conf
logger blahblah
ssh autoloader@192.168.0.1 \
  copy http://192.168.0.32/cisco/automatic.conf running-config
```

**Automatic invocation** On the web server, have a cron job like this:

```
* * * * * /path/to/dowholething.sh
```

Obviously you could do any configuration you like with this method.  You might also consider source-based routing into a blackhole rather than straight blocking.

Comment: Thank you jonathanjo, by setting up 1 honeypot in AWS I have seen around 100 requests from different IP addresses and this is just 1 I plan to deploy ~20 in different datacenters and other cloud services... wondering if I can define in ASA a unique ACL which will grow eventually when I add these IP address programmatically ? (Example: using expect).